# How to get all options of a select using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get all the options of a select through jQuery by passing on its ID?

I am only looking to get their values, not the text.

Answer (score 690, accepted):

Use:

```
$("#id option").each(function()
{
    // Add $(this).val() to your list
});
```

[.each() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: None of the JavaScript operations require jQuery. jQuery is a matter of choice to simplify JS operations.

Comment: you can also do:

$("#id option").each(function(name, val) {
   var opt=val.text;
});

Comment: `$('#id option').map((index, option) => option.value)` : note how the callback signature is reversed compared to the "vanilla" JS `map` function (`(item, index) =>`)

Comment: Upvoting this answer because the original question was how to do it with jQuery - so then the answer should use jQuery, not vanilla JS

Answer (score 195):

[Without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
I do know that the [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) element contains an [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) property, which is a [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection).

```
const myOpts = document.getElementById('yourselect').options;
console.log(myOpts[0].value) //=> Value of the first option
```

A 12 year old answer. Let's modernize it a bit (using `.querySelectorAll`, [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the resulting `HTMLOptionsCollection` to `Array` and map the values).

```js
// helper to retrieve an array of elements using a css selector
const nodes = selector => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];

const results = {
  pojs: nodes(`#demo option`).map(o => o.value),
  jq: $(`#demo option`).toArray().map( o => o.value ),
}
console.log( `pojs: [${results.pojs.slice(0, 5)}]` );
console.log( `jq: [${results.jq.slice(0, 5)}]` );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="demo">
  <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
  <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
  <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
  <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
  <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
  <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
  <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="North Korea">North Korea</option>
  <option value="South Korea">South Korea</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
  <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
  <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1. Don't resort to jQuery's complex selector magic for things that already have quite efficient implementations built into the plain old DOM.

Comment: Why not, @bobince? If you mostly use jQuery it's quicker both with less code to be written, and quicker to not try and figure out if you should switch to regular javascript in this instance. And your code is more consistent.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew. jQuery is highly optimized and uses the quicker native functions wherever possible. I also like the simplicity of jquery selectors.

Comment: @bobince The original question was how to do it with jQuery ...

Answer (score 167):

`$.map` is probably the most efficient way to do this.

```
var options = $('#selectBox option');

var values = $.map(options ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

You can add change options to `$('#selectBox option:selected')` if you only want the ones that are selected.

The first line selects all of the checkboxes and puts their jQuery element into a variable. We then use the `.map` function of jQuery to apply a function to each of the elements of that variable; all we are doing is returning the value of each element as that is all we care about. Because we are returning them inside of the map function it actually builds an array of the values just as requested.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMO. Map is a very powerful construct that fits exactly this situation.

Comment: I really like your solution - it's the approach I went with. However, if you just want the selected values it's even more trivial: `$('#selectBox').val()` will return an array of the selected values.

Comment: Hi, @PCasagrande I have a custom attribute name 'data-type'. How can I get the value of this using your solution? What I am doing is 'option.data-type', but this is giving me NaN. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @PCasagrande I got what I needed by doing '$(option, this).attr("data-type")'. But if you have anything better then do let me know. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think you can just do 'return option.attr("data-type");' in the map. That should give you an array of the values of the data-types.

Answer (score 81):

Some answers uses `each`, but `map` is a better alternative here IMHO:

```
$("select#example option").map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get();
```

There are (at least) two `map` functions in jQuery. Thomas Petersen's answer uses "Utilities/jQuery.map"; this answer uses "Traversing/map" (and therefore a little cleaner code).

It depends on what you are going to do with the values. If you, let's say, want to return the values from a function, `map` is probably the better alternative. But if you are going to use the values directly you probably want `each`.

Comment: You can actually use this.value instead of $(this).val() here. You'd also be better served by finding the children in the initial selector (#example option). Nice tough with the get() at the end though.

Comment: @Alex Barret: Well, it's possible to solve this problem without using jQuery at all. Calling jQuery with an element as argument will just wrap the element in a jQuery object (i.e. no tree traversing, i.e. not that expensive). So maybe as a micro-optimization, yes.

Comment: map FTW. This is exactly how it should be done. The get() on the end seems unnecessary, however (that returns the DOM node, and val() already gives us a string, so...?)

    var opts = $('#cm_amt option').map( function() { return parseInt($(this).val()); } );

Comment: @sbeam: "As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to `get()` the returned object to work with a basic array." -- http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: It helped me very much, I wanted the text not the value, so I just changed to `text()` instead `val()`. Thank you ! (I caused you go over the 1000 `;->`)

Comment: This wouldn't work if your select contained option groups as the `.children()` function would return the optgroups instead of the options themselves.

Answer (score 65):

```
$('select#id').find('option').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This is the ticket, because I like to cache elements into variables on init, rather than use the selector.

Comment: Also works with $(this) (which is what  was looking for) e.g,

Answer (score 28):

This will put the option values of **`#myselectbox`** into a nice clean array for you:

```
// First, get the elements into a list
var options = $('#myselectbox option');

// Next, translate that into an array of just the values
var values = $.map(options, e => $(e).val())
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$("#id option").each(function()
{
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Although, the **CORRECT** way is to set the DOM property of the element, like so:

```
$("#id option").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be .attr('selected', 'selected') ?

Answer (score 12):

You can take all your "selected values" by the name of the checkboxes and present them in a sting separated by ",".

A nice way to do this is to use jQuery's $.map():

```
var selected_val = $.map($("input[name='d_name']:checked"), function(a)
    {
        return a.value;
    }).join(',');

alert(selected_val);
```

Comment: this code is pretty unreadable, I'd never use it even if its kinda cool.

Comment: also the question is about `select` and `option` not checkboxes.

Answer (score 7):

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/usizo/110/edit)

The most efficient way to do this is to use `$.map()`

**Example:**

```
var values = $.map($('#selectBox option'), function(ele) {
   return ele.value; 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code for that:

```
var assignedRoleId = new Array();
$('#RolesListAssigned option').each(function(){
    assignedRoleId.push(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For multiselect option:

`$('#test').val()` returns list of selected values.
`$('#test option').length` returns total number of options (both selected and not selected)

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use `toArray()` in order to use fat arrow function with map e.g:

```
const options = $('#myselect option').toArray().map(it => $(it).val())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example in jquery to get all the values, texts, or value of the selected item, or text of the selected item

```
$('#nCS1 > option').each((index, obj) => {
   console.log($(obj).val());
})
```

```js
printOptionValues = () => {

  $('#nCS1 > option').each((index, obj) => {
    console.log($(obj).val());
  })

}

printOptionTexts = () => {
  $('#nCS1 > option').each((index, obj) => {
    console.log($(obj).text());
  })
}

printSelectedItemText = () => {
  console.log($('#nCS1 option:selected').text());
}

printSelectedItemValue = () => {
  console.log($('#nCS1 option:selected').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="1" id="nCS1" name="nCS1" class="form-control" >
     <option value="22">Australia</option>
          <option value="23">Brunei</option>
          <option value="33">Cambodia</option>
          <option value="32">Canada</option>
          <option value="27">Dubai</option>
          <option value="28">Indonesia</option>
          <option value="25">Malaysia</option>    
</select>
<br/>
<input type='button' onclick='printOptionValues()' value='print option values' />
<br/>
<input type='button' onclick='printOptionTexts()' value='print option texts' />
<br/>
<input type='button' onclick='printSelectedItemText()' value='print selected option text'/>
<br/>
<input type='button' onclick='printSelectedItemValue()' value='print selected option value' />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var arr = [], option='';
$('select#idunit').find('option').each(function(index) {
arr.push ([$(this).val(),$(this).text()]);
//option = '<option '+ ((result[0].idunit==arr[index][0])?'selected':'') +'  value="'+arr[index][0]+'">'+arr[index][1]+'</option>';
            });
console.log(arr);
//$('select#idunit').empty();
//$('select#idunit').html(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple Script with jQuery:

```js
var items = $("#IDSELECT > option").map(function() {
    var opt = {};
    opt[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
    return opt;
}).get();
var selectvalues = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    for(key in items[i]) {


        var id = key;
        var text = items[i][key];

        item = {}
        item ["id"] = id;
        item ["text"] = text;

        selectvalues.push(item);

    }
}
console.log(selectvalues);
copy(selectvalues);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple way to generate a list of comma separated values.

```
var values = "";

$('#sel-box option').each(function () { 
   values = values + $(this).val() + ";";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox][checked]").serializeArray();
```

Or:

```
$(".some_class[type=checkbox][checked]").serializeArray();
```

To see the results:

```
alert($("input[type=checkbox][checked]").serializeArray().toSource());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all options with some selected text then the below code will work.

```
$('#test').find("select option:contains('B')").filter(":selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

The short way

```
$(() => {
$('#myselect option').each((index, data) => {
    console.log(data.attributes.value.value)
})})
```

or

```
export function GetSelectValues(id) {
const mData = document.getElementById(id);
let arry = [];
for (let index = 0; index < mData.children.length; index++) {
    arry.push(mData.children[index].value);
}
return arry;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it short and simple, and can be tested in Dev Tool console itself.

`$('#id option').each( (index,element)=>console.log(` index : ${index}, value : ${element.value}, text :   ${element.text}`) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select#MY_SELECT_ID").find('option').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```