# How to get all "option" values in "select" by Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I get all values in the select by Jquery?

Example:

```
<select name="group_select" id="group_select">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

Which I want to get all option values (a,b and c) from select (without selected any option) by using jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all options of a select using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var values = $("#group_select>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
```

Comment: I had to add a .get() to the end...

`var values = $("#group_select>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();`

Comment: @plong0 yes we have to use val() to get it in Array

Answer (score 22):

The following will give you an array of the `<option>` values

```
var values = $.map($('#group_select option'), function(e) { return e.value; });

// as a comma separated string
values.join(',');
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/usizo)**. add **/edit** to the URL to see the code.

Comment: Thanks for the `values.join(',');` , this answer was more applicable to my solution.

Comment: Single line: `var $('#group_select option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join();`  [link(http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 4):

This will iterate through all the options and give you their values. Then you can either append them to an array or manipulate them individually.

```js
$('#group_select option').each(function(){
  $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: I think closing bracket of each loop missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code for that :-

```
var assignedRoleId = new Array();
$('#RolesListAssigned option').each(function(){
        assignedRoleId.push(this.value);
        assignedRoleId.push(this.text);
});
```