# jquery getting all dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown `<select>` with id `my_dropdown`.  I allow multi-select.  I know how to pull the selected value(s) using jquery:

```
var values = $('#my_dropdown').val();
```

This will return an array of values if I select multiple.  I also need to get all the values in the dropdown regardless of what is selected.  How can I use jquery similarly to get all the values in the dropdown given that id?

Comment: better solution found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery

Answer (score 37):

How about something like:

```
var values = [];
$('#my_dropdown option').each(function() { 
    values.push( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like:

```
var values = $('#my_dropdown').children('option').map(function(i, e){
    return e.value || e.innerText;
}).get();
```

See this in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/16/

Reference: [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: return e.value; (if you want values instead of displayed text)  Otherwise, this is a great solution! +1

Comment: I always forget about the `map` function +1

Answer (score 5):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FadHu/

```
var opts = $('#my_dropdown')[0].options;

var array = $.map(opts, function( elem ) {
    return (elem.value || elem.text);
});
```

The `<select>` element has a list of the options in its `options` property. Then [use `$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), which returns an array, to get either the option's `value` or `text` property.

*(Note the `$.map()` behaves a little differently from `$(element).map()`. Can be a little tricky.)*

Comment: I like the fall back to text if there is no value :p

Comment: @John - Yeah, necessary for IE6, or if the `value` for some reason is an empty string. Otherwise, most browsers will give you the `text` if there isn't a `value` attribute present.