# Idiomatic jQuery to get all options in a listbox into comma-separated string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Where lb is a listbox, txtfield is a textbox, this code takes all the values of the options, puts them in an array and makes it into a comma-separated list:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = lb.options[i].value;
}
txtfield.value = arr.join(',');
```

lb.options.toString() obviously doesn't work because it's an array of options (value and text).  I haven't found anything more succint than this.

What's the jQuery way to do this?  I tried messing around with `$(lb).each()`, but can't seem to get it to work in the same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all options of a select using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Comment: @epascarello not a duplicate of that because I'm using the $(domelement) since I already have a DOM element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
txtfield.value = $(lb.options).map(function() { 
                                       return this.value; 
                                   }).get().join(',');
```

This [uses `.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create a jQuery object by returning the `value` of each `option`, then [uses `.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to extract the Array from the object.

---

**EDIT:** As [@Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) noted in the comment below, if you need to get optimal performance (with jQuery), it makes more sense to use [the `$.map()` variation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) since you already have a collection. [See his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199826/idiomatic-jquery-to-get-all-options-in-a-listbox-into-comma-separated-string/4199864#4199864) for details.

---

**EDIT:** To get better performance, do your `for` loop, but cache the references to the properties. It [makes a difference](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-jquery-map/3).

```
var arr = [], opts = lb.options, len = opts.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = opts[i].value;
}
txtfield.value = arr.join(',');
```

Comment: In these cases it's far better to use `jQuery.map()` which is much less wasteful/faster, you can test it here: http://jsperf.com/map-vs-jquery-map

Comment: Thanks all for the very thorough investigative work.  I shall weigh keeping an optimized version of the loop code (which is better than what I was refactoring in the first place) vs. something which might be more succint or maintainable.

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery version is [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```
var arr = $(lb).find("option").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
txtfield.value = arr.join(',');
```

Or a bit faster with [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) like this:

```
var arr = $.map(lb.options, function(o) { return o.value; });
txtfield.value = arr.join(',');
```

However, both are **significantly less efficient** than a `for` loop, go with the plain JavaScript version you already have.

Answer (score 6):

Look at [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)..

```
$('#lbID option').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the jQuery equivalent to your code. There are more elegant solutions, though.

```
var values = [];

$(lb).children('option').each(function () {
   values.push($(this).text());
});

$(txtfield).val(values.join(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

Could do it like this but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve?

```
$('option', $(lb)).each(function() { arr.push($(this).text()) });
```

Comment: Spent 10 mins getting that working and there another three similar answers already here!

Answer (score 2):

See demo here: [**Fiddler Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/938n3h87/)

you can get the multiple selected option Text values with separator.

```js
 $('#testID').change(function () {
        var test=$(this).find("option:selected").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join('//');
     alert(test);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">test Value1</option>
    <option value="2">test Value2</option>
    <option value="3">test Value3</option>
    <option value="4">test Value4</option>
    <option value="5">test Value5</option>
    <option value="6">test Value6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Get dropdown selected Value" id="select-values">
    <div id="result"></div>
```