# How do I gather dropdown values into array with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all options of a select using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery)

I have the following code I need to gather all the possible options into a 2D array detailing the value and the text shown.

```
<div class="input-box">

    <select name="options[4]" id="select_4">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="24">Not Sure - Send Me Some Samples First </option>
        <option value="13">1 Jet Black </option>
        <option value="14">Blondette 4/27 </option>
        <option value="15">Boho Blonde 613/12 </option>
        <option value="16">Caramel 6 </option>
        <option value="17">Cherry 530 </option>
        <option value="18">Dirty Blonde 612/12 </option>
        <option value="19">Ebony Black 1b </option>
        <option value="20">Hot Toffee 4 </option>
        <option value="21">LA Blond 24/613 </option>
        <option value="22">Malibu Blonde 60/613 </option>
        <option value="23">Raven 2 </option>
    </select>

</div>
```

I am really not sure how to do this, I would normally give my attempt so far but I know its less than useful.

```
myarray = $('.input-box').eq(0).val();
```

Comment: Should the value be the key of the array, and the text the value of that key? Or should both the value and the text be a value in the array under the same key?

Comment: Both the value and the text should be availbale under the same key. So that it can loop through the values easily.  The idea, is to show a bunch of colour swatches depending on the values available in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Thanks for the help guys!

```
$j('.input-box:eq(0) option').each(function() {
    alert($j(this).val()+' :: '+$j(this).text());
});
```