# Adding items to an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to add elements to a specified element.  So a user selects options from a drop down menu and it's appended to a div.  My jQuery is:

```
    $('#datacombo').on('change', function () {
    var selecteddata = $("#datacombo").val().toString();   
     $('#datadisplay').append("<p>"+ selecteddata + "</p>"); });
```

my HTML is simple a div:

```
<div id="datadisplay"></div>
```

I'm wanting to use ALL the 'selected data' at a later point so i want to add the selected items to a variable array.

I've searched on here and tried these:
[How do I gather dropdown values into array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564243/how-do-i-gather-dropdown-values-into-array-with-jquery)

But couldnt get it to work, any suggestions?

Comment: `var array = $('#datadisplay p').map(function () {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare array as global variable. And then push elements to it.

```
  var selectedDatas = new Array();

  $('#datacombo').on('change', function () {
     var selecteddata = $("#datacombo").val().toString();   
     selectedDatas.push(selecteddata);
     $('#datadisplay').append("<p>"+ selecteddata + "</p>"); 
  });
```

Comment: This sounds like a lie but i tried this, for some reason it didn't work (maybe where i declared the selectedDatas array.  Tried this and it worked).
Thanks!

Comment: @Hagbard ) If you are using Google Chrome, may be it cached your javascript files and dont update it.  Most of the time it is happening to me.

Comment: I am indeed using Google Chrome that may have been it