# Java Get ALL elements from a multiselect Box

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a multi-select Box and I'm doing some javascript to sort the order of the elements in the box.  I want to submit the **whole** array after sorting back to the Java and not just the select items.  How can I achieve this?

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#mup")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveUpItem);    
        $("#mdown")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveDownItem);    
    });   

    function moveUpItem(){  
        $('#list option:selected').each(function(){    
            $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());   
        });  
    }   

    function moveDownItem(){    
        $('#list option:selected').each(function(){    
            $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());   
        });   
    }       
</script> 



<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="center">
            <h1>DET Column Maintenance</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="process.det_column_order" method="post" name="detColumnSortorder" >
    <table class="data_table">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                <select id="list" name="fieldNames" size="35" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px;">
                    <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}">
                        <option value="${field.fieldName}">${field.displayName}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <button id="mup">Move Up</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button id="mdown">Move Down</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input name="action" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>   
 </form>
```

FORM:

```
 private String[] fieldNames;
public String[] getFieldNames() { return this.fieldNames; }
            public void setFieldNames(String[] val) { this.fieldNames = val; }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since forms only submit the selected values, you'll need a little more JS and another form field.

Introduce a hidden form field that will hold the values you care about:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldNamesOrder" id="fieldNamesOrder"/>
```

And after every click of Move Up/Move Down:

```
var order = [], sel = document.getElementById("list");
for(var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++) {
    order.push(sel.options(i).value);
}
document.getElementById("fieldNamesOrder").value = order.join(",");
```

Then, on the server side, you can read your ordered field names out of that posted field.

Comment: DAMMIT!!! You beat me by like 1 second!!! Although, you answer is a lot more detailed than mine!!! +1 :)

Comment: Technically I need them all...Im going to roll them up in a list and do an UPDATE statment on on a table and update the order of the fields

Comment: right, so the hidden field (i.e. Request["fieldNamesOrder"] or however your framework accessess posted data) contains every option, in order.

Comment: Instead of doing this on every mouse-click he could register and onsbumit event handler for his form and do this, too... could save some client-side resources

Comment: I did this instead.....seems much cleaner `$(document).ready(function() { $("#submit").click(function() { $("#list").each(function(){ $("#list option").attr("selected","selected"); }); $("#detColumnSortorder").submit; }) ; });`

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create a hidden text field in your HTML form that stores the values from each of your options... or you need to programatically select all of the options before the form is submitted.