# How to deal with unsuccessful iframe loading?

Tags: javascript, html

My app allows users to view pages in an iframe, but pages like www.google.com, will generate an error

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by
>   X-Frame-Options.

and pages like [stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery), will send me a alert saying:

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the
>   frames.

How should I detect these situations and friendly tell user what happend with a genric message, such as "This page is restricted access, please directly access it from a new tab.'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is because many site include frame buster. The error you are getting is most likely related to ajavascript process trying to access the parent window and getting an access denied error.

One of the possible solution will be to build a proxy on your server that fetch the html and serve it from your domain but many site won't like that either and might even trouble you for it.

Comment: The above answer is incorrect. The error you are getting is not a javascript issue. The website has marked that it is not allowed to be shown in an iframe (via header data), and thus the browser is respecting the other websites wishes.