# Select all values of a HTML select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I get a HTML `select` option, which I generate with PHP. The names of the options are the folders in a directory. Now I need the  value in my jQuery script. I just know the commands `$('#select :selected').text()` or `$(#select).val()` but both just bring me the current selected option.

The select box with PHP:

```
<select id="existAlbum" name="existAlbum" size="1">
    <option>SELECT ALBUM</option>
    <?PHP
        foreach ($alledateien as $datei) {

            $dateiinfo = pathinfo($album."/".$datei);
            if ($datei != "." && $datei != ".." && $datei != "background.jpg" && $datei != "loading.gif") {

                echo ('<option>' . $datei . '</option>');
            };
        };
    ?>      
</select>
```

Is it possible to add all the values in a jQuery Array?
I need to compare the option values with other words.

Comment: Already answered I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery

Comment: @Bruno: Yes and no. It's a similar question, but i don't want to use the value option... so the solution by johan is great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    var optionValues = [];

    $('#existAlbum option').each(function(){
        optionValues.push(this.value);
        //or if you want to use the jquery methods on each option:
        //$(this).val()
        //with your current code, you would need $(this).text(), 
        //since youre not adding any values
        //"this" is the current DOM element (<option>)
    });

    //do stuff with the optionValues-array here

});
```

Comment: Question. How can i compare this one? This is how i do it, but something went wrong: for(var i in optionValues)
   {
    if(newAlbum == optionValues[i]){ 
     alert('fail');
    }
   }

Comment: @dTDesign Hard to say without the complete code, but you could try a different approach: `if( $.inArray(newAlbum, optionValues) !== -1 ) { alert('fail'); }`

Comment: Or i explain what i wanna do: In the array i got all albumns in a directory. now i want to check if the "newAlbum" the same like one of these albums in the directory. hope you understand, sorry for that.

Comment: @dTDesign Your code looks ok to me. Did you try out my code from the comment as well?

Comment: Oh. My fault. I forgot something else in the code. sorry. thank you for your help. +1

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `value` of each option in markup

```
echo ('<option value="' . $datei . '">' . $datei . '</option>');
```

With proper markup now implemented get the array of all options values:

```
var optsArray= $('#existAlbum option').map(function(){
   return this.value  // or $(this).text()
}).get()
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/XDm4F/1/

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i dont want to display a multi-select option

Comment: OK.. I misintepretd.. you want all values...see added `map` solution