# jquery delete 'select option' element value except the second option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i delete the value of each `select option` element except the second `option` value :

```
<select name="_users_id_requester" onchange="submit()">
  <option value="0">-----</option>
  <option selected="" value="774">Asmaa El Habib,Yassine</option>//except this one 
  <option value="779" title="Ahlam Edouiri - U8K8O">Ahlam Edouiri</option>
  <option value="746" title="Ainane Mohamed - MohamedAinane">Ainane Mohamed</option>
</select>
```

i have tried some thing like this but i don't know how to end it :

```
$("select[name='_users_id_requester']").each(function(){
  if ( $(this).index() > ..... )
    $(this).attr("value", " ");
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824/how-do-you-remove-all-the-options-of-a-select-box-and-then-add-one-option-and-se Here you'll see how to clear the select options list and add the element you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go like

```
$("select[name='_users_id_requester'] option").not(":eq(1)").val('');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("select[name='_users_id_requester'] option").not(":eq(1)").prop('value', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some selectors to select precisely do what you want as the [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) one.

```
$("select[name='_users_id_requester']").find('option:not(:nth-child(2))').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value", "");
});
```

The `:nth-child` selects a precise child and the `:not` do a sort array subtraction. It subtracts all the ones match by the not the with the whole array.

Here is a working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGCxf/). Just look at the HTML using Chrome or Firebug