# How can I use JSF 2.0 values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF drop down box...

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Select a criterion" noSelectionOption="true"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Map location: Main land US"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="Map location: Alaska"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem itemValue="6" itemLabel="Map location: Hawaii"></f:selectItem>
```

And this JavaScript function...

```
function initialize() {
    //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.8722222,-113.9930556);
    //map centered for US display
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024,-95.712891)  
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

I want to add some if statements that let me set the latlong section to different items

```
if (itemValue == 5)
{
    //alaska
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64.0000,-150.0000)
}
if (itemValue == 5)
{
    //hawaii
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.3114,-157.7964)                                     
    //end new shit
}
```

but I am unsure of how to pass the item values from the JSF drop down list to the javascript function.

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: you can find a lot of alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you look at the rendered HTML for the dropdown, since that's all that Javascript can work with. Basically, you'd have to select the HTML element by id, class, or any other selector, then get its value.

If you're using jQuery, here's a simple way to get the itemValue:

```
var selectedItemValue =  $('.mySelector').children("option:selected").val();
```

...where mySelector is a styleClass assigned to the selectOneMenu tag.