# Javascript DOM variable is reference instead of copy

Tags: javascript, dom

I was using the code below from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590197/3473971)

```
var myOpts = document.getElementById('yourselect').options;
console.log(myOpts);
//prints HTMLOptionsCollection [ <option>, <option>, <option>, <option>, <option> ]
```

Now, after I had already stored the contents of the select in the variable, I used jQuery to empty the select using:

```
$('#yourselect').empty();
console.log(myOpts);
//prints HTMLOptionsCollection { length: 0, selectedIndex: -1 }
```

And to my surprise, the variable was empty as well. 
My understanding was that the variable was a copy, not a reference to the DOM element.

Why does this behavior happen? And is there any way I can prevent it?

Comment: If you want to keep `myOpts` you would have to copy it instead of assigning it. You are using `myOpts=document.getEle...` and in Javascript that will always be assigned by reference since it is a complex type.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, any reference to a DOM element is only a reference, elements are not copied.

Comment: [`element.options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties) is documented to be a reference to the HTMLOptionsCollection instance for that element. If you'd like to copy the data in that instance to a new object, may I recommend `Object.assign`?

Comment: Everything in javascript is a reference, you have no choice in the matter. All arrays are references and you cannot treat them as values, all objects are references and you cannot treat them as values, all array-like objects (like HTMLOptionsCollection) are references and you cannot treat them as values. The exception to this rule is strings, numbers and booleans - those are the ONLY value-like types in the language and you also have no choice in the matter, you cannot treat strings, numbers and booleans as references.

Comment: @slebetman Uhh... Actually everything in JS is _value_ , which maybe a copy of a reference, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Comment: @Teemu: No. Everything is a reference. But arguments to functions are passed by copy to reference (in a language like C we'd call it pass by value). But we're not talking about arguments to functions here so we're talking about variables - which are references. How variables behave and how arguments are passed to functions are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to accomplish both is use jQuery [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```js
var $opts = $('#mySelect option').detach();

console.log('Stored options =', $opts.length)
console.log('Active options =',  $('#mySelect option').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="5">Item 5</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to the actual object in the DOM by design. You can clone it by using `<elem>.cloneNode()`, and storing that in a variable.