# How can I convert (binary) integer into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, binary

I have the following form select field in my HTML code -

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="uploadSites[]" id="uploadSitesDecoded">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
    <option value="4">Site 3</option>
    <option value="8">Site 4</option>
    <option value="16">Site 5</option>
    <option value="32">Site 6</option>
</select>
```

Now I'd like to pre-select the options based on an integer value, e.g. the value 15 should pre-select Site 1, 2, 3 and 4.

As far as I know this can be done using the jQuery trigger method -

```
$('#uploadSitesDecoded').val([1,2,4,8]).trigger('change');
```

So what I'm trying to do is to convert 15 to a string or array as 1,2,4,8 (unless someone knows an easier way).

Comment: Just in case there are others like me who are guessing at what the conversion formula is, can you please detail what logic you are expecting to be ran against 15, or any number, to get the resulting array?  As it is, I see that 1+2+4+8 = 15, but that's just me guessing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all options of a select using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery)

Comment: The fact that a select is involved is peripheral. The crux of the question is numeric conversion.

Comment: these are binary values, so e.g. 1111 (=15) would be Site 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Why does this seem like somebody writing C got into web development and decided to use boolean masks for options, instead of just sending an array?

Comment: I'm not a C developer :) actually I'm writing this in my spare time to learn :) I only want to store a single value into the DB instead of all the options.

Comment: Will probably help future readers if you edit your question details to clarify that the input integer represents a binary number and that you want to create an array of values that correspond to the "on" positions (where the bits have a value of 1). So "15" results in `[8, 4, 2, 1]` because "1111" contains "1" values at each of those positions while "6" would result in `[4, 2]` because "110" contains "1" values at only the "4" and "2" positions. Not sure the parenthetical in your title gets the message across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parseInt(n, 10).toString(2)`

This will give you the bit by bit representation of n, you can then loop through it char by char to get the power of 2 values corresponding:

```
let n = 15; // The number you want to turn into an array of power of 2
let array = [];
let binaryRepresentation = parseInt(n, 10).toString(2);
binaryRepresentation = binaryRepresentation.split("").reverse().join(""); // You need to reverse the string to get the power of 2 corresponding
for(let i = binaryRepresentation.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
     if(binaryRepresentation[i] == 1){
         array.push(Math.pow(2, i));
     }
}
console.log(array); // Check the array
```

This exemple will give you `[8, 4, 2, 1]`

Comment: Thanks! Nearly what I was looking for, but looks like 6 would return [2,1]

Comment: My bad, you need to reverse the string, edited my answer. It should work as expected now, but do not hesitate to tell me if something is going wrong

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to achieve this is to convert the integer value in to a binary string using `toString(2)`. Then you can loop through the string and set the `option` matching the index of the string to selected, if the value is a `1`. Something like this:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var $options = $('#uploadSitesDecoded option');
  var binaryString = parseInt(this.value, 10).toString(2);
  binaryString.split('').reverse().forEach(function(n, i) {
    $options.eq(i).prop('selected', n === '1');
  });
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="1" min="0" max="63" /><br />
<select multiple class="form-control" name="uploadSites[]" id="uploadSitesDecoded" size="8">
  <option value="1">Site 1</option>
  <option value="2">Site 2</option>
  <option value="4">Site 3</option>
  <option value="8">Site 4</option>
  <option value="16">Site 5</option>
  <option value="32">Site 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the most optimal way, but here is my solution.
First I change the given int to a binary and than reverse it. Than loop over it to find the `1`'s in the binary.

```js
function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}

function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var binary = reverseString(dec2bin(15));
  var values = [];
  var step = 1;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(binary.charAt(i)) === 1){
      values.push(step);
    }
    step *=2;
  }
  
  $('#uploadSitesDecoded').val(values).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple class="form-control" name="uploadSites[]" id="uploadSitesDecoded">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
    <option value="4">Site 3</option>
    <option value="8">Site 4</option>
    <option value="16">Site 5</option>
    <option value="32">Site 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying find an array of numbers that are both:

1. power of two (2^n)
2. less then 15

You may use Array.filter to accomplish this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
let powerOfTwo = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

let result = powerOfTwo.filter(function(item) {
  return item < 15
})

// the result should be [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Comment: Turns out that OP is actually looking for an array of values that represent the 1 bits of the binary equivalent of the input value. That means that if the input value were "6" instead of "15", OP needs an array of `[2, 4]` while your suggested approach would produce an array of `[1, 2, 4]`. No worries though, OP's objective is not very clear in the question details at the moment, and your answer is a good, simple way of producing the example output in the question.