# document.getElementsByName returns null in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am trying to get all the possible options of a `<select>` whose name is `wpv-collection`. Unfortunately I am not even able to get all the values to iterate through them. I am getting an empty json.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var collectionsOriginaldropdown = document.getElementsByName('wpv-collection');
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(collectionsOriginaldropdown)); 
});
```

Comment: If you want to loop through the options, do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590219/519413), if you want all options as an array or comma separated string, do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760197/519413)

Comment: That is not my question. My question is why I am getting a null value when I do document.getElementsByName when the wpv-collection select is definetly there

Comment: To answer your edited title, `getElementsByName` will return an empty node list if nothing is found in the DOM matching the provided name. As you've not provided any HTML to demo the issue, we cannot help you debug it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — No, it won't. It will return an empty node list.

Comment: But it is there when I inspect the file

Comment: This is the output of the json: {"0":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"9":{}}}

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a node list containing zero or more HTML elements. Neither node lists, not HTML elements are things which make sense to pass to `JSON.stringify` so your test to see if you can get the values is flawed.

Comment: @Quentin true, updated.

Comment: @Maria — An object containing a bunch of empty objects is **not remotely** the same as `null`!

Comment: So if I try this: 
  var collectionsOriginaldropdown = document.getElementsByName('wpv-collection');
    window.alert(collectionsOriginaldropdown[0][1].val); I am getting undefined when the options are there

Comment: Then there is another problem in your code, as you should be seeing JSON containing empty objects: https://jsfiddle.net/02xL9ur1/

Comment: Why would a `val` property be defined in the first place? There's no such thing in DOM.